# Multiple selection of dropdown menu and direct to a link

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am looking for JavaScript or in jquery for my custom dropdown menu

```
<form name="menu">
<select ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

   <option value="" selected="selected">Courses</option>

   <option value="http://www.google.com">Course1</option>
   <option value="http://www.youtube.com">Course2</option>
   <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Course3</option>
                 </select>

    <select ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

   <option value="" selected="selected">Location</option>

   <option value="http://www.google.com">Location1</option>
   <option value="http://www.youtube.com">Location2</option>
   <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Location3</option>
                 </select>
</form>

http://jsfiddle.net/kundansingh/d4FEV/2/
```

in this if i select any of the course and then the location it should redirect to a paticular url, so for each course, different locations will be there and url

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

1. Just pass the value(url) to a javascript function as an argument.
2. Grab that value in that javascript function.
3. Redirect the url (might use  window.location.assign(url) function)`